# a href (image) side by side not responsive

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am creating a  2 a href which i use image to this which is side by side and need to be responsive . But the problem is when i view it in phone it is not responsive. The a href position in different angle. Below is my code. I want the a href image to be side by side and make it reponsive.

HTML

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<section id="new">



<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-6">
     <img class="img-responsive" src="1.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 text-center">
      <h2>You get detailed feedback from attendees</h2>
      <p class="lead">We provide unique insights & analytics into who attended, their engagement, and their review of your event.
      </p>


    </div>

    <div class="col-6 col-sm-3"><a href="#"   >
            <img id="app" src="app-store-badge.png"/>

          </a>
</div>
  <div class="col-6 col-sm-3"><a href="#"   >
            <img id="app" src="app-store-badge.png"/>

          </a>
</div>

    </div>
  </div>
</header>



</section>
```

CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
  .title{
  color:#00BD8B; margin-top: -180%; font-weight: bold; 
}
#bg {
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 

  /* Preserve aspet ratio */
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.row {

  color: #fff;
}



</style>
```

Comment: What [@media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) have you tried?

Comment: 1024x768 @media i use

Comment: Update your question with whatever media queries you're trying and be more specific about what exactly you're struggling with (position, width, other elements, etc).